# How to use DI correctly with entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have several classes (called providers) that are injected into controller properties, respectively their interfaces. These provider classes get all an IDatabaseProvider class injected, because I need to have the same db context. The life cycle for all injected classes is set to web request.

The problem is when I update a database entity. The values are correctly stored into the sql server, but if I query them still the old values are returned. If I refresh the page of the mvc application, the retrieved data is up-to-date. I suppose it is related to the lifecycle of the DI classes. But even if I set them to transient, I have the same problem.

I highly appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your implementation.

Comment: Are you calling `SaveChanges()` somewhere before requesting the data again?

Comment: yes, I call save changes. From this point I see the changes in the sql server. After SaveChanges I retrieve the data again in a method that is inside a class that has the db context injected, and the values are not the updated ones. I suppose the db context that is injected is somehow still the same as before the update has happened.